# When if an FFT more efficient than Goertzel?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, dft, algorithms, frequency-domain

Given a block, $x[n]$, of M samples.

Calculating abs(fft(x)).^2 returns the power spectrum of that block through the use of a $M$-point FFT.

I can calculate the same using Goertzel's algorithm.

At which $M$ will it be more efficient to use an FFT instead of Goertzel?

Comment: What do you mean by *power of N* ? is it $2^N$ frequency points? That's to say, you want to compute a $2^N$-point DFT of M-point sequence x[n], using either an FFT or the Goertzel algorithm..?

Comment: By power of N I mean the power of N frequency points. I want to either compute an N-point FFT of an M-point sequence which returns N frequencies OR I want to compute it using Goertzel. My question is: For which N is an FFT more efficient than using Goertel?

Comment: @james3849 You didn't answer Fat32's question. If N = 4 what is the "power of N"?

Comment: @RichardLyons Sorry for not being clear. Read it as "power of N frequencies" and not "power of N". In other words, I am interested in calculating the power of N frequency bins.

Comment: Ha ha! I thought your statement *Let's say I want to run a frequency analysis that returns the power of N equally spaced frequencies.* indicated that you run a DFT that calculates (returns) **power of $N$**, (that's to say $a^N$ for some $a$ not indicated) equally spaced frequency points. That's why I asked for clarification of the term *power or N*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you implement the Goertzel algorithm P times to detect P different
spectral samples, Goertzel is more efficient (fewer multiplies) than the N-point FFT when P < log2(N).